# Best solution for quickly loading a level select screen with 100+ buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, cocos2d-iphone

I have a level select screen similar to candy crush's (a path of levels) where I plan to have more than 100 levels. When I load this many levels in one go, the time to create and load all of these levels is ~0.17 seconds. Now this is clearly much too long to wait after a user presses a button to go to the level. The game appears to freeze for a bit, then it finally goes.

Now I've been looking at a few different solutions to this. The one solution which I could revert to as a last resort is creating some sort of transition that temporarily shows a loading screen, then goes to the level select screen. It would be nice to bypass this loading all together though.

Currently my level select screen is a normal CCNode class with a scrollview on it. This means it is not a singleton, and every single time I go to it, a new instance loads. The nice thing about this is that I can constantly update whether or not someone has beaten a level, and change the color and ability to play the next level (is it possible to make this kind of update in a singleton class?). A singleton seems like the best approach to me (then I would just load in while the game loads at the beginning), but I'm not sure if the answer to my above question is yes. If someone has experience with this, please let me know!

I'm not really sure what else I could try to do. The only other good option seems to be somehow speeding up my code, but I'm not sure how I could do that (posted below). The last resort would be creating an instance of this class while my game loads, then just hide all user interaction on it whenever I don't want it to be showing. Idk though, that sounds a little sketch. Thanks for the advice, and here is my code creating the buttons.

```
-(void)didLoadFromCCB{
    buttonArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    CFTimeInterval startTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
    CCSpriteFrame *redTile = [CCSpriteFrame frameWithImageNamed:@"Sprites/glossyTile.png"];
    for (int l = 0; l < NUMBER_OF_WORLDS; l++) { //NUMBER_OF_WORLDS = 10
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
            NSString *tempTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",(k+1)+(l*5)];
            tempButton = [CCButton buttonWithTitle:tempTitle
                                          spriteFrame:redTile
                                          highlightedSpriteFrame:redTile
                                                 disabledSpriteFrame:nil];
                tempButton.block = ^(id sender) {
                CCNode *transitionScene = [CCBReader load:@"TransitionScene"];
                [self addChild:transitionScene];
                int row = k+1;
                int column = j+1;
                int buttonIndex = (row + (column-1)*5) + l*20;
                for (int m = 1; m < buttonIndex; m++) {
                    [[LevelManager sharedInstance] nextLevel];
                }
                levelNumber = i;
                [self performSelector:@selector(changeScenes) withObject:nil afterDelay:8.0/30.0
                 ];
            };
            tempButton.position = ccp(someConstant*j, someConstant2*k + someConstant3*l);
            [self addChild:tempButton];
            i++;
            }
        }
    }
    CFTimeInterval elapsedTime = CACurrentMediaTime() - startTime;
    CCLOG(@"time interval media %f", elapsedTime); //logs about 0.17 seconds
}
```

Comment: You could think about loading just the needed buttons for one screen. On scroll load the next row. Basically what UITableView or UICollectionView does. That should be fast enough and you won't consume that much memory when you scale this up

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, I'll check that out